# What would cause an ajax request to fire multiple times from a jQuery dialogue button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a partial View that creates the following html:

```
<div id="tabs-3" style="display: block;">
    <div id="My_List">
    </div>
    <button id="create-log"  role="button"> Create new Comment </button>
  <div id="dialog-log">
      <input type="hidden" value="6265" id="My_ID"/>
      <div><label>Title</label><input id="My_Title" type="text" value=""/></div>
      <div><label>Message</label><textarea id="My_Message">...</textarea></div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

The partial View also renders the following script block just below the html.

```
<script>

$(function () {

    $("#dialog-log").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: "auto", width: "auto", title: "Add Comments to the Log",
        position: { my: "center top", at: "center top", of: window },
        buttons: {

            "Create Comment": function () { UTIL.CreateComment($("#My_ID").val(), $('#My_Title').val(), $('#My_Message').val(), $(this)); },
            Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
    $("#create-log").button().click(function () {
        $("#dialog-log").dialog("open");
    });


});

</script>
```

The layout View includes a Utility.js file. It declares a script literal that facilitates the ajax call in the dialogue's "Create Comment" click event.

```
var UTIL = {

HandleAjaxError : function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown, fn) {
    switch (textStatus) {
        case "timeout": alert(fn + "\n\nStatus:server timeout"); break;
        case "error": alert(fn + "\n\nStatus:general error \nError Thrown:" + errorThrown); alert("object status: " + jqxhr.status + "\nresponse text \n>>>\n" + jqxhr.responseText + "\n<<<\n"); break;
        case "abort": alert(fn + "\n\nStatus:abort"); break;
        case "parsererror": alert(fn + "\n\nStatus:parsererror \nError Thrown:" + errorThrown); alert(jqxhr.responseText); break;
    }
    //alert(jqxhr.responseText);

},
CreateComment: function ($Id, $Title, $Message, $dlg) {

    var mydata = "ID=" + $Id + "&Title=" + $Title + "&Message=" + $Message;

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "/Log/Create/", type: "POST", dataType: "html", data: mydata

    }).done(
    function (returnhtml) {
        $('#My_List').html(returnhtml);
        $('#My_Title, #My_Message').val("");
        $dlg.dialog("close");

    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { UTIL.HandleAjaxError(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown); })

}
}
```

So what happens in the browser is that sometimes - for reasons that I cannot explain - multiple ajax calls are fired when the user clicks the "Create Comment" button created by the dialog. This occurs randomly, but frequently... enough to make me worry.

What's more is that the number by which ajax calls are repeated varies - sometimes it's 3-5 and other times it's 11-15 ...

My question is more related to technique since I cannot replicate the behavior in any way, though it happens periodically in the production environment.

I need reputation of 10 to post the screenshot ...

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause it to happen multiple times. Try narrowing it down a bit.

Comment: Sorry if i'm completely blind but I dont see  "Create Comment" button.. Also - is the button being created every time your popup appears? is the event getting bound everytime your popup appears? there is probally multiple click events added to the  "Create Comment" button.

Comment: @JFit it's a dialog button: `"Create Comment": function () { UTIL.CreateComment` so no it isn't being generated or bound to multiple times.

Comment: *"My question is more related to technique since I cannot replicate the behavior in any way, though it happens periodically in the production environment."* Try running in IE8 standards and clicking really fast. My guess is this is just a case of impatient user spam clicking. One way to stop it would be to close the dialog before you send the ajax request rather than after.

Comment: Hi Kevin, my gut was telling the internal jQuery function that creates the dialogue window (and creates the button) binds this function to the click event 'n' number of times ... but I have no way of knowing or testing if this is indeed what is happening. What's more strange is that when I close the dialog (without reloading the page) and open it up again the ajax call is just fired once... what am I missing?

Comment: Nothing, i think my previous comment explains what is happening. The user's browser hangs while their slow network connection handles the ajax request, at which point the user impatiently clicks the button again causing a second, third, etc ajax request.

Comment: Does the dialog close after the first ajax call ?

Comment: @Lorenzo - Hi - Yes the dialog closes after the first ajax call.

Comment: Did you try to `return false;` in the `done()` function after `$dlg.dialog("close");`

Comment: Does the bug also occur if you don't use JQuery? if so, you can debug it more easily that way.

Comment: @Lorenzo - Will try that, but it's pretty hard to replicate the behavior (firing off multiple ajax requests) since it only happens periodically. Will also close the dialog before calling the $.ajax() and pray.

Comment: I would also try `event.preventDefault()`  ###  

buttons: {
    
        "Create Comment": function (event) { 
           UTIL.CreateComment($("#My_ID").val(), $('#My_Title').val(), $('#My_Message').val(), $(this)); 
           event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Kevin B the issue might simply be that people keep pressing the button.

You should include a "sending" option when the button is pressed and then disable it.

This can be accomplished in multiple ways, but the easiest is to set a flag:

```
CreateComment: function ($Id, $Title, $Message, $dlg) {
  // avoid multi-sending
  if($dlg.data().sending)
     return;
  $dlg.data().sending = true;

  var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "/Log/Create/", type: "POST", dataType: "html", data: mydata

   }).done(
    function (returnhtml) {
        // reset sending flag so in when opening the dialog again, another comment can be sent
        $dlg.data().sending = false;
        $('#My_List').html(returnhtml);
        $('#My_Title, #My_Message').val("");
        $dlg.dialog("close");

    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $dlg.data().sending = false;
...
```

This way it checks if the dialog is already sending data and will not run until the data is actually sent (on the done/fail the variable is reset)

This should take care of browser bugs or multi-clicking.

Comment: Thanks a Billion! I ended up setting the flag via a property in the script literal instead of utilizing the dialog's data() because I was paranoid about the functions that manipulate the DOM to open & close the dialog. But really thanks for the advice. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: I did a variant of this approach and it has solved my issue - thanks @Niko! Useful tool to recreate the issue and to verify the fix worked in the end was a Chrome extension Click.Repeat: set the interval to .2 seconds and you pass in the xpath of the button you want clicked. Was not able to recreate the issue by mouse clicking manually.